# Problem installing UniversalIndentGUI

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center

I need a GUI beautifier for C code. I've found UniversalIndentGUI on sourceforge. Downloaded a .deb file.Opened it with Ubuntu Software Center to install it but the button is grey and unclickable and there is a line saying

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libqscintilla2-3.

I've installed via the Synaptic Package Manager libqscintilla2-5 but that didn't help. Is there any way to install the UniversalIndentGUI, the libqscintilla2-3 package or to some how work around the problem?

Comment: See answer below, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed the package "universalindentgui" with Synaptic Package Manager instead of trying to install the .deb file with Ubuntu Software Center.The Manager installed 8 other  packages but I think all of them were the terminal tools used behind the GUI (such as astyle , uncrustify etc). The Manager didn't however installed a package with a similar name to "libqscintilla" or any of listed in blueXrider answer.The application seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sourceforge may not be the best source for this. There is a PPA for UniversalindentGUI
2. Usually dependencies for your distribution are not being met because it was compiled for a different distro version. ie: installing something from Natty instead of Precise.
3. Refer to the Launchpad for correct documentation [HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/universalindentgui)
4. Prior to installation download the build dependencies stated.

Current stable version:

Build dependencies

```
debhelper (>= 8.0.0)
libqscintilla2-dev
libqt4-dev
quilt (>= 0.46-7)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering blueXrider , but i found a very simple solutions tath works for me. Read my answer for details.